# Import swift file into objective-c project

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I have a problem, I import the swift file correctly, but some of the methods of the swift are not imported in an objective-c. I use SweetAlert in my project.

[This code from SweetAlert.swift](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPKde.png)

But when generated interface header file (CashCourier-Swift.h) , it imported only the first function.

[This is generated interface header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWoFc.png)

Like all did the right thing, but I can not use a showAlert function with multiple parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The enum `AlertStyle` causes the problem. Swift enums can only be bridged to Objective-C enums if they have basic integer type (e.g. `Int`) raw value (they also have to be marked with `@objc` attribute). The enum couldn't be bridged, so methods which use it are not visible from Objective-C.